# displaying image with dimensions using smarty template

Tags: php, smarty

I am using smarty template to render a page on the fly; this is how I am assigning the variables in the php file:
$imgsrc1, $imgsrc2, $imgsrc3 contains the location of the uploaded image files

```
$smarty->assign('foto1', $imgsrc1);
$smarty->assign('foto2', $imgsrc2);
$smarty->assign('foto3', $imgsrc3);
```

In the template file, I am using them in this way:

```
<img src='{$foto1}' border='1' width="230" height="250">
<img src='{$foto2}' border='1' width="630" height="850">
<img src='{$foto3}' border='1' width="130" height="150">
```

I know this is NOT the ideal way to display images. This does the job; only that height and width are not taken; the native height and width is displayed. I guess I shoud use {html_image}, but I don't know how to assign and then use it to display in the template.

Edited:
Please note that it is not just the display of the images, I want to control their sizes. For example image1 must have a fixed size of 230 x 250 and image2 must have fixed size of 630 x 850 and image3 must have a fixed size of 130 x 150, irrespective of the original attributes of the uploaded files.

Comment: To understand your question, let me rephrase it with my words: You want width and height to be according the image in your variable `$fotoX`?

Comment: yes, also let me know how to assign it too

Answer (score 1):

You've already hinted the easiest way, using [`{html_image}`](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.html.image.tpl).

If you don't want to change your php code...

```
$smarty->assign('foto1', $imgsrc1);
$smarty->assign('foto2', $imgsrc2);
$smarty->assign('foto3', $imgsrc3);
```

...then you might want to just change your smarty template to...

```
{html_image file=$foto1}
{html_image file=$foto2}
{html_image file=$foto3}
```

This simplifies your task at hand because you let smarty do the job to discover the actual image size.

The generated html code will look something like this:

```
<img width="230" height="250" alt="" src="/path/to/your_image1.jpg">
<img width="630" height="850" alt="" src="/path/to/your_image2.jpg">
<img width="130" height="150" alt="" src="/path/to/your_image3.jpg">
```

If you want to have more control about the output, you have to move the image handling over to php. If this is what you want, please contact me.

**Update**

Since you clarified that you want to control the width and height basically without checking the source images dimensions, you don't have to analyze the image, which is what `{html_image}` does. Instead just push the dimensions variables into the template too, maybe like this.

PHP code:

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array(
        'path' => '/path/to/your_image1.jpg',
        'wdth' => '230',
        'hght' => '250'
    ), 
    1 => array(
        'path' => '/path/to/your_image2.jpg',
        'wdth' => '630',
        'hght' => '850'
    ), 
    2 => array(
        'path' => '/path/to/your_image3.jpg',
        'wdth' => '130',
        'hght' => '150'
    )
);

$smarty->assign('images', $arr);
```

smarty template code:

```
{foreach $images as $img} 
    <img src='{$img.path}' border='1' width="{$img.wdth}" height="{$img.hght}">
{/foreach}
```

Please keep in mind I used an array here just to visualize the dependencies better. This can of course be done without the use of an array.

Comment: I want ability to control the attributes (height & width) of the images. Images with their native sizes are already being displayed with the code I posted in my query. I want to a fixed height and width attribute to each of the image.

Comment: In that case, please clarify this in your question (if not already done). I'll update my answer later.

Comment: I think smarty does not let one mess with image attributes; it displays the native height and width only. There are some plugins that allow image resizing; I am checking on that.

Comment: Updated, though I feel this is a rather static approach.

Answer (score 0):

in php loop like this:

```
$newArray = array();
$imagesArray = [$imgsrc1,$imgsrc2];
for(i = 0;i<count($imagesArray);$i++;){
   list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imgsrc1);
    $newArray[$i]['src'] = $imgsrc1;
    $newArray[$i]['width'] = $width;
    $newArray[$i]['height'] = $height;
}
$smarty->assign('imagesArray', $newArray);
```

Then in smarty loop like this:

```
    {foreach from=$imagesArray key=myId item=i}
        <img src='{$i.src}' border='1' width="{$i.width}" height="{$i.height}">
    {/foreach}
```

have not tested the code, there might be minor syntax problems.

Comment: I got your point. It is not just displaying the images. I want to control their sizes. For example image1 must have a fixed size of 230 x 250 and image2 must have fixed size of 6300 x 850 and image3 must have a fixed size of 130 x 150, irrespective of the original attributes of the uploaded files.

Comment: will this solve ur problem:

$imagesArray = array('0' => array('src' => $imgsrc1, 'width' => '200', 'height' => '300'), '1' => array('src' => $imgsrc2, 'width' => '400', 'height' => '500')];

then loop it in smarty

Comment: I think smarty does not let one mess with image attributes; it displays the native height and width only. There are some plugins that allow image resizing; I am checking on that.